Is there an easier version of this structure: "What must it have been like to do something a thousand years ago."

What must it have been like to witness the northern lights a thousand years ago?

The structure "What must it have been sounds too wordy, academic and difficult to pronounce if you enunciate each word. And it doesn't seem to flow easily for a non-native speaker.
For some reason, I believe there must be an easier structure used by native english speakers in every day life.  So, I wonder do native english speakers really use it in their daily lives or do they have a simpler version with the same meaning?

Yes. What must it have been like .... a hundred years ago.  Not so big a number.

There are many ways to phrase a similar question but "What must it have been like..." isn't pompous or academic or a tongue-twister.  You could say "I wonder what it had to be like..."

It's not obvious to me that What must it have been like to... conveys anything different to What was it like... But I'm guessing most people today have never seen the Northern Lights, AND they wouldn't know what causes the phenomenon anyway, so most likely the average reaction to seeing them for the first time today is much the same as it was 1000 years ago or 10,000 years ago. Things (or at least, people) were probably quite a bit different 100,000 years ago, though.

I lost a lengthy answer halfway through, but "I wonder what it must have been like" is a way to un-invert the syntax, making it a bit more everyday. But I agree that the original is fine for everyday speech, though I understand about it being a mouthful.

If the question is rhetorical, a really casual equivalent would be like "it'd be so crazy to be a peasant in the middle ages". Or "I wonder what it'd be like to witness the northern lights a thousand years ago"

"what must it have been like" is often used to express a sense of awe or wonder. "What was it like" is more mundane.


do native english speakers really use it in their daily lives?

I can't recall using that expression recently in daily life.
However, when reading it the register it strikes is not overly literary, pompous, wordy, academic or difficult. No.  It sounds normal.
The phrasing may admittedly be a bit advanced.  It's somewhat literary sounding. A new language learner would not start out speaking that way.  But eventually, sure.
A simpler version:
Imagine... what was it like ... to witness the northern lights a thousand years ago?

@Yunus thank you for the vote! you have gotten me over 10k!  About 5 years ago I was thinking how cool it would be to view moderator tools.  Now I don't care but it's still a sort of milestone.
